# What Swing Component should be used for a table

Tags: java, swing

What JCompoment is used to make the table on the top of the picture?

I know that it is a Swing component, but I do not know what each individual division is.

[image: Password Store GUI]

Comment: [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the Oracle tutorial, [How to Use Various Components](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/componentlist.html).

The top section is a JLabel and a JTextField.

The middle section is a JList inside of a JScrollPane.  The contents of the JList are Objects that have an icon, host name, account name, and password.

The bottom section is a JTabbedPane.  The JPanel shown displays the currently selected Object from the JList.

I'm not sure what the bar image on the lower right represents.

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like a table, most probably it is a `JList`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really tell by just looking at the image.
The scrolled portion is *probably* a JList inside a JScrollPane, but could just as easily be a JScrollPane containing a JPanel with a Box layout where the JPanel contains multiple JPanels with Flow layout that contain several items, or it could be a JScrollPane containing a JPanel that uses a GridBagLayout to display multiple items, or any number of other possible things.